# Index of substring start point?

Tags: java

I am completely new to Java, had never seen computer code till one week ago, I managed to put together this code, but cannot quite get my head round the following concept:

When representing my first substring to start at `int F`, it would make more sense to me for the code to execute correctly at `F = s.length();`, not `+1`, because s is 11 characters.  The index that starts one after the `d` and print nothing is `s.length()+1;`, but it seems as though that would start at two indexes after the word has finished. Like my second substring, when it executes, G will be at 3, meaning it will start at the second `l` and fill the gap as required. Can anyone clear this up for me?

Thank you.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "hello world";
        String rep = s.replaceAll("[a-z]", " ");
        int F = s.length()+1;
        int G = 2;

        for(int i = 0; i<s.length(); i++, F--, G++)
            if (i == 0 || i >= s.length()-1){
                System.out.println(s);
            } else {
                System.out.println(s.charAt(0) + rep.substring(F) + s.charAt(i) + 
                    rep.substring(G) + s.charAt(s.length()-1));
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you check the v.alue of `i` in your loop ? Print the index value and the length of your `String` on each iteration. This is a cheap version of debugging, good enough for a start. You should spot your problem quickly. Also, still not sure off what you want to do. See [ask] and maybe check how to write a [mcve]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you add to your question your expected output and what the program actually prints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're thinking is correct; for doing your substrings, `F` should start at `s.length()`.  The reason you need to add a `+ 1` is because you go through the loop once before you get to your substring code.

The first time you go through your loop, you print out `s` and continue.  Now on your second iteration, `i = 1`, `G = 3`, and `F = s.length()`, because the for loop has added 1 to `i` and `G` and subtracted 1 from `F`.

So, in reality, the substring part you are concerned with does start with `F = s.length()`, it just is hard to see in your code.

Here is a modified version of your code, which does the same thing, but starts with `F = s.length()`.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "hello world";
        String rep = s.replaceAll("[a-z]", " ");
        int F = s.length();
        int G = 3;

        System.out.println(s);
        for(int i = 1; i<s.length()-1; i++, F--, G++)
            System.out.println(s.charAt(0) + rep.substring(F) + s.charAt(i) +
                rep.substring(G) + s.charAt(s.length()-1));
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, yes I can see that now! Bit silly really, I understood the loop, but was overlooking that basic concept. Thank you!